# Translating matplotlib plot axes labels in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, translation

I have written a notebook that prepares several plots which I will later embed in an article. However, this article will be publisihed in different languages. I wonder if there is a simple way of translating the strings that appear in a Jupyter notebook, so I can generate the same figures, but with the appropriate language for the plots.

I had in mind something like the Django approach, in which you can compile a `po` file based on what gettext finds, but I honestly wouldn't know how to get started within a notebook.